# How exactly does DQN learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I created my custom environment in `gym`, which is a maze. I use a `DQN` model with `BoltzmannQPolicy`.
It trains fine with the following variables:

- position of the agent
- distance from the endpoint
- position of the endpoint
- which directions can it move to

So I don't give it an image or anything. If I train and test it in the same environment (the same maze, without changing the position of walls) it can solve it easily. But if I introduce it to a completely different environment (maze) without the training then it doesn't know what to do. I don't know if the problem is with my code, or `DQN` is just for solving the same environment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: @desertnaut Okay then, where can I ask this question?

Comment: Please notice that, when we provide links, we clearly imply that they contain guidance, too; please see the 2nd link provided (I suggest Data Science SE). That said, my guess is that your question lacks the necessary details, so I would suggest including them when posting there. If you do so, you should also delete this one, as cross-posting is [not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: Just a quick comment on this question since it is here, it appears you are "memorizing" the maze and not learning to generalize to the maze problem. It fails when you change the maze because it isn't exactly like the trained maze. Sometimes called "OVERFIT"...

Comment: @mazecreator Okay, so how could I generalize the problem? What should I use?

Comment: @marci These is a lot of theory & means to accomplish that, you should probably take this question to the Data Science group: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/